# Troubles using Wake on LAN

Tags: networking, motherboard, lan, wake-on-lan

I hope I'm posting to the right place, and apologize if it is not.

I am trying to set up WoL on my computer but am having trouble.

I went into my Realtek Network adapter through the device manager and enabled "allow magic packet to wake the computer" in power management.

I then went to my motherboard's BIOS and made sure that my wake up config for "resume by PCI or PCI-E device was enabled.

Along with disabling the ECO settings.

I Tried using an app through my phone by putting in my computers IP and MAC addresses, but it does not seem to be working. i don't know if there is a setting I am missing, or if I am not inputting the correct addresses.

Any help would be appreciated.

OS: Windows 10

Motherboard Z77A-G43

Thanks

Comment: you may not be doing anything wrong. I've never come across a scenario where WOL worked correctly across the board. there is always some issue. I gave up on it years ago. Good luck.

Comment: Did you make sure your phone was on Wi-Fi (not cell data) when you ran the tool? And that that Wi-Fi is bridged (not routed or NAT-gatewayed) to the same Ethernet LAN that the WoL Ethernet NIC is on?

Comment: @Spiff my phone was on wi-fi. And I'm not 100% sure what you mean by bridged. I'm guessing you don't mean bridge mode, because it is not in that.

Comment: Try sending WOL messages for the standby / sleep system.